# External Link issue in Visual Form Builder Pro

Tags: links

I am building a form in VFBPro and I have a conditional field that loads depending on which radio button is checked. The conditional field has instructions that require the user to click an external link. I entered the link as    a href="http://www.domain2.com". When I go to the form to test it, the browser is pointed to    mydomain.com/"http://domain2.com".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong.  This was a bug affecting descriptions that's been fixed in version 2.2.1.

Here are the [release notes](http://vfb.matthewmuro.com/release-notes/).